# html - how to make background image of table tag on top of background color in table's td tag?

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
    <table style="background-image:url('Images/thermometer.png');">
        <tr>
            <td width="299px" height="789px" style="background-color:#cc0000">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

But the bg colour appears on top of the bg image. How can I reverse this?

Thanks. Also note that I can't use html5 or css3.

Comment: Not possible to my knowledge... because the `<td>` is a child of `<table>`, it will always stack on top. Unless you reverse the `style` properties

Comment: Why you want to give background color and hide it using an image? instead better don't give a background to the td

Comment: Its because I'm making a thermometer, and for the bg image, near the center of the image is transparent, and thats where I will place td tags with its bg color being red. Maybe there is a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use absolute positioning of an image on top of the table if absolute positioning is possible.

```
<div style="position:relative;">
    <table style="position:absolute; left: 10px; top: 10px;">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <img src="#.png" alt="" style="position:absolute; left: 10px; top: 10px;" />
</div>
```

If you need the image to stretch with the page width, make the width a %. That way, you could assign the style of the parent div like this:

```
<div style="width: 50%;left: 25%; top: 10px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put the background colour on the tables parent element